# TSQL Error: A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-function

I am just trying to create a function that returns a select statement, but it gives the error:

> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

This is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Sample] (@SampleValue int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
RETURN(
 SELECT * FROM View_sls
)
```

Please let me know the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrong syntax, that's all. You don't need `BEGIN` when you have an "inline table-valued function"

See [CREATE FUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) and example B

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Sample] (@SampleValue int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
 SELECT * FROM View_sls
);
GO
```

Comment: giving error Cannot perform alter on 'dbo.xxxx' because it is an incompatible object type

Comment: @KrunalShah: it's a different type of function so DROP and CREATE. Their are 3 kinds of UDFs

Comment: i dropped it and Created it - still giving me same error!

Comment: @KrunalShah: ask a new question. it's unrelated to this.

Answer (score 11):

Two things:

- you need to **define the structure** of the table you want to return
- you need to add data into that table

*Then* you can call `RETURN;` to return that table's data to the caller.

So you need something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Sample] (@SampleValue int)
RETURNS @returnTable TABLE 
                     (ContactID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                      FirstName nvarchar(50) NULL, 
                      LastName nvarchar(50) NULL, 
                      JobTitle nvarchar(50) NULL, 
                      ContactType nvarchar(50) NULL)
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @returnTable
        SELECT ContactID, FirstName, LastName, JobTitle, ContactType
        FROM dbo.View_sls

    RETURN;
END
```

Comment: My table view_sls is really big, so I don't want to define all the columns one by one, is there an alternative ?

Comment: I assume OP wants an inline TVF, not a multi-statement one

Comment: +1 for finally giving me a working example (almost.. not sure if it's the same, but I'm using MS SQL, and couldn't get it working until I removed the `;` after `RETURN`)

Answer (score 3):

You need to describe the returned table, populate it, then `RETURN`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Sample] (@SampleValue int)
RETURNS @RESULTS TABLE
(
  ID int, <other fields>
)
AS BEGIN

  INSERT @T
    <select ...>

  RETURN
END
```

Comment: My table view_sls is really big, so I don't want to define all the columns one by one, is there an alternative ?